# gradlew missing in generated android project

Tags: java, android, gradlew

Okay I'm trying to do some android developing via command line / with an alternative IDE.

I have the following path variables set up:

- jdk1.8.0_40/bin/
- android-sdk-linux/tools/
- android-studio/bin/
- android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/

I run this command to make a project:

```
android create project --target 2 --name MyFirstApp --path ./MyFirstApp --activity MyActivity --package com.example.myfirstapp
```

The tutorial tells me to cd into MyFirstApp and run.

```
gradlew assembleRelease
```

There is no gradlew in this directory!

```
$ cd MyFirstApp/
$ ls
AndroidManifest.xml  build.xml         proguard-project.txt  src
ant.properties       libs              project.properties
bin                  local.properties  res
```

I've been trying for days but I need help doing this:

> Use Gradle to build your project in debug mode, invoke the
>   assembleDebug build task using the Gradle wrapper script (gradlew
>   assembleRelease).

Comment: the ``gradlew.sh`` and ``gradlew.bat`` are alway the same, you could copy from another project.

Comment: Is this a gradle project? Where is the `build.gradle` file? Project build seems to be setup using `ant`. Have a look at the `build.xml`.

Comment: l ran "$ gradle init" in the "MyFirstApp" directory and it produced some new files including a "build.gradle".

Answer (score 9):

This is called the gradle wrapper, you have to generate it first. In your main build.gradle file, put:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.0'
}
```

Then run:

```
gradle wrapper
```

This has to be run once and you will get the gradlew file. You can then remove the wrapper task from your build.gradle file.

Comment: Using the gradle I found at "android-studio/gradle/gradle-2.2.1/bin/" I ran "$ gradle init" in the "MyFirstApp" directory and now I have the gradlew I was searching for. I'm not sure where to go from here my comprehension is pretty low at this point.